# jQuery Waypoints fire at bottom of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

so since I don't know much about jQuery and am mostly copying and pasting codes, while I still try to understand them, I mostly fail at the last part - understanding.
Well, so now for my problem:
I'm building a Onepager with a navigation on top with 4 navigation-points: work, skills, about, contact (same id's).
I'm trying to toggle a class when a certain span is reached, so that the link in the nav is highlighted.
This works fine up to contact - which is at the bottom of the page.
So I already searched quite a while and found out it may have to do something with offset attribute. But I just can't get my head around how to add it, so that the last waypoint triggers, when the user reaches the bottom of the page - and again, when the bottom gets out of sight.

This is my js-code so far:

```
$('#work').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-work').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'down');
});
$('#skills').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-work').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'up');

});
$('#skills').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-skills').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'down');
});
$('#about').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-skills').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'up');
});

$('#about').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-about').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'down');
});
$('#contact').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-about').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'up');
});

$('#contact').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-contact').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'down');
  {offset:'bottom-in-view'};
});
```

As you can see I already tried out something with the last part but that just doesn't work for me.
Also: I'm building my site fully responsive - I and avoid explicit Pixel-heights and -widths. I'm mostly working with vh and vw.
Another note: My footer's height is 20vh.
This is meant to work through all devices.

I would really appreciate your help since I've already gone through all related topics here and in the internet and just can't find a solution for me.

To make it more clear I'll try to give you the relevant code parts of html and css (since the whole page's code would be too much and doesn't give a good overview.)

```
HTML:

    <!--Nav-->
            <div class="sticky-nav">
                <a href="#start"><img src="images/Bildmarke.svg" alt="home"></a>
                <p>lisa röhl</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="nav" id="nav-contact" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" id="nav-about" href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" id="nav-skills" href="#skills">skills</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav" id="nav-work" href="#work">work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
<span class="anchor-work" id="work"></span>
<span class="anchor" id="skills"></span>
<span class="anchor" id="about"></span>
<span class="anchor" id="contact"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.nav:hover{
        color:#e76600 !important;
    }
    .nav-hover{
        color:#e76600 !important;
    }
.contact-down{
    height:20vh;
    background-color:#2b3534;
} /*Note:This is the css of the div, where the contact-part is in - so the height of the "footer"*/
```

I hope this helps out :)

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle or a jsbin?

Comment: a whole jsfiddle seems to be hard for me, since I make the page on my personal PC here and it's already quite much code that it would take ages to transfer it.. but I'll try to filter the relevant parts and add it in my question above, just a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fobecunaye/edit?html,css,js

I am using the no dependencies version of waypoints, Basically by default waypoints checks if the entire element is in view, adding a small view point offset fixes any scrolling issues. The following is the code for your contact element.

```
   //This is the code for the bottom div (or in your case a span) 
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('contact'), //Select element
  handler: function(direction) {
    $('span').removeClass('nav-hover');
    // The preceding line just removes all elements with nav-hover class, deselecting them
    $('#nav-contact').addClass('nav-hover');
    // This line just adds the nav-hover class
  },
  offset: 3 // Tells waypoint to instantiate when the element is 3px away from the top 
});
```

Variables Waypoint throught Waypoint4 will replace your existing js. Also the version of waypoint has been changed to the following

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

### I'd Be glad to help if you have any questions..

EDIT: Okay, I think I found the problem in the code,

```
$('#contact').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-contact').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'down');
  {offset:'bottom-in-view'};
});
```

Should be:

```
 $('#contact').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#nav-contact').toggleClass('nav-hover', direction === 'down');
}, {
  offset: 'bottom-in-view' 
});
```

The {offset...} part should be another parameter in waypoint you just put in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help - but still, not working :(
More like it's worse - I tried the code from your Jsbin, adjusted to my id's of nav and then nothing works anymore.
Isn't there a way using my code above? Since it's already working for all nav-ids except the "contact" part, which would be at the bottom inside a footer.

Comment: See my updated Edit, It seems you are using the version with a jquery dependency, I wasn't which caused your code to break. You might have to mess around with the offset property to get your desired outcome.

Comment: Yes, that may be true :)
But thank you! Now it just works fine though I still have to mess around with the offset, so that it looks smoothly :)
Just as I thought...I just didn't get, how to include that "offset"-attribute to the code :) So, thank you very much! You helped me out a lot!